# Matlab standalone app that was compiled using Guide and deploy tool does not work as designed when deployed

Tags: matlab, dll, matlab-guide

I am not sure if this info helps, but my GUI tool has text boxes for user input, push buttons, drop downs, and an axes to show histogram plot.

The deployment machine is a Windows 7 64 bit. The MCR is installed without any issues (using mcr file packaged with the GUI). The GUI opens in deployed machine. However it does not function properly. Just gives beep sound when using any functionality like pressing a button, no error messages are shown.

I ran the exe file through the dependency walker, and it shows the following errors:

```
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
LAUNCHERMAIN.DLL
```

(Error opening file. System cannot find the file specified) for all the above.

Comment: Run the executable from a dos window in order to obtain all messages that normally would write to matlab console ... I'm suspecting that some matlab routines used in your buttons were not embedded during compilation (and the beep corresponding to "warning, error in gui callback function "lalala" is undefined).

Comment: NB: I don't think there is any issue for missing dll in dependency walker ... else your exe would not run at all and would wrote "Failed to load module"

Comment: @CitizenInsane - Your response helped me resolve the issue. I am not able to select your comment as the answer, could you kindly answer the question so I can acknowledge it. I executed the application from DOS and it threw an error, which I was able to fix. The error was not related to dlls. My application was not able to resolve a path for an input file. It was a simple fix once I knew what the error was. Thanks again.

Comment: Great that it was it and that it works ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the executable from a dos window in order to obtain all messages that normally would write to matlab console ...

I'm suspecting that some matlab routines used in your buttons were not embedded during compilation (and the beep corresponding to "warning, error in gui callback function "lalala" is undefined).

NB: I don't think there is any issue for missing dll in dependency walker ... else your exe would not run at all and would wrote "Failed to load module".

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing the Visual Studio redistributable package.  Download and install it on the deployed machine.